# TYPO3 8.7 can not override FORM Templates files

Tags: forms, typo3-8.x

I've tried to override the Templates in Form extension but it doesn't work in latest TYPO3 version 8.7.0.

I tried like below but it's not Work.

```
plugin.tx_form {
 settings {
   yamlConfigurations {
     10 = fileadmin/form//BaseSetup.yaml
    }
 }
}
```

My `BaseSetup.yaml` file look like this.

```
    TYPO3:
      CMS:
        Form:
          persistenceManager:
            allowedFileMounts:
              10: 1:/user_upload/
            allowSaveToExtensionPaths: false
            allowDeleteFromExtensionPaths: false
            #allowedExtensionPaths:
              #10: EXT:example/Resources/Private/Forms/

          prototypes:
            standard:

              ########### DEFAULT FORM ELEMENT DEFINITIONS ###########
              formElementsDefinition:

                ### BASE ELEMENTS ###
                Form:
                  __inheritances:
                    10: 'TYPO3.CMS.Form.mixins.formElementMixins.BaseFormElementMixin'
                  rendererClassName: 'TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Renderer\FluidFormRenderer'
                  renderingOptions:
                    __inheritances:
                      10: 'TYPO3.CMS.Form.mixins.translationSettingsMixin'
                    templateRootPaths:
                      10: 'fileadmin/form/Resources/Private/Frontend/Templates/'
                    partialRootPaths:
                      10: 'fileadmin/form/Resources/Private/Frontend/Partials/'
                    layoutRootPaths:
                      10: 'fileadmin/form/Resources/Private/Frontend/Layouts/'
```

Any one help me Please.

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is mistake in your given filepath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is okay,as i know.
I think there is mistake in your file path:

```
10 = fileadmin/form//BaseSetup.yaml
```

Change to :

```
10 = fileadmin/form/BaseSetup.yaml
```

Comment: Yes Right! just my small mistake. Thanks